# Twig replace keyword dynamically

Tags: twig

I wonder why this do not work

```
{% set what = 'hate' %}
{% set byValue = 'like' %}
{{ 'I hate twig'|replace( { what : byValue } ) }}
```

It should display `I like twig` isn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax to create associative arrays using Twig is:

```
{key1: value1, key2: value2, 'key3': value3, (key4): value4}...
```

Take care here:

- key1 and key2 are HASH KEYS
- 'key3' is a string
- (key4) is an EXPRESSION (it evaluates your key4 variable)
- value1 ... value4 are variables

HASH KEYS are basically literally considered as strings.

So, your array:

```
{ what : byValue }
```

Will create an array with a `what` key, instead of the content of your `what` variable. If you want to use an expression instead of a hash key, you just need to wrap your hash key (or even a number) with parenthesis.

```
{ (what) : byValue }
```

Answer (score 6):

Just wrap the key with parentheses and Twig will treat it as a variable:

```
{{ 'I hate twig'|replace({ (what): byValue }) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Should

```
{{ 'I hate twig'|replace( { what : byValue } )) }}
```

be

```
{{ 'I hate twig'|replace( { what : byValue } ) }}
```

Comment: edited it was a typo, same issue. As you can know, twig doesn't let typos intepreted and throw an exception.

Comment: You're right it should have been a comment, or an edit suggestion actually.